# How to remove background

Tags: adobe-illustrator

There are some fonts that won't show up in AI, so I type it in PS and save as EPs file and open in AI. The problem Im facing is that when I copy the text to another work, the background will also be copied. How do I delete the background cause when I use selection tool it will select the whole rectangle, not just the text.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Save as **.psd** and open *that* with Illustrator. When asked, choose to "Convert Layers to Objects"

This should allow the type to come in to Illustrator either as live type or on its own layer.